# How can I upload screenshots from my Wii U?

Tags: wii-u

There was a Wii U software update yesterday, and browsing [Nintendo's support site](http://www.nintendo.com/consumer/systems/wiiu/en_na/system_system_update.jsp?menu=general_info&submenu=wup-online-gi-update), I noticed this interesting tidbit:

- Ability to launch the Internet Browser during gameplay and upload screenshots

Now, I am **all about** taking and uploading some screenshots, (How else will I integrate free hand circles on my answers?) but I've not been able to figure out how to take the screenshots promised by this new update.

What should I be doing if I want to take a picture of the current screen?

Comment: Feature request for Nintendo, ability to freehand draw with the Wii controler on screenshots!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Have the desired image displaying on your television and/or Gamepad
2. Press the Home button on your Gamepad
3. Press Internet browser
4. Go to the site where you want to upload, And press the browse or upload button. (I did this at Imgur.com and postimg.org)
5. When choosing what to upload on our preferred site, you are prompt, on which screen to upload (Gamepad or TV).