# How can I take a screenshot of my Mii on a Wii-U?

Tags: wii-u

Following on from [How can I upload screenshots from my Wii U?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/132971/how-can-i-upload-screenshots-from-my-wii-u) I'd like to know how to take a screenshot of my Mii.

I'm growing a moustache for [Movember](https://au.movember.com) and I've just added a moustache to my Mii to reflect my current appearance. I want to take a screenshot of my Mii and post it to Facebook.

The screenshot feature doesn't work from all software titles and I haven't found one that will work yet. So far I have tried from the home screen, the Mii editor in User settings and in Wii Fit U. Every time I try it I get a message saying "No uploadable images."

Comment: Well, you could buy and use Roxio Game Capture, but there still has to be an official way of capturing a Mii right on the Wii U...

Comment: In the answer on the question you linked, what step does it fail on?

Comment: @Pyritie Step 5

Answer (score 1):

Start up Mii Maker and press "QR code/image" on the GamePad, then press "Save Mii as image". You can then choose your Mii and it will save a picture of it on your SD card.